# Drop Nan from dictionary values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I would like to drop the Nan values from the dictionary which are in the following list:

Example

```
List_a = [{key_1: 'green', 'key_2': 'blue', 'dataframe': datetime   value1  value 2
                                                         2020-01-01   2      3                    
                                                         2020-01-02   Nan    2                    
                                                         2020-01-03   3      4                   
           }]
```

So i would like to drop the Nan values from the dataframe key, so the result would look like this:

```
List_a = [{key_1: 'green', 'key_2': 'blue', 'dataframe': datetime   value1  value 2
                                                         2020-01-01   2      3                                       
                                                         2020-01-03   3      4                   
           }]
```

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research and what went wrong with your attempt(s)? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] so that we better understand how to help you. For example, indexing ito the dictionary and using the pandas [dropna() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for dct in List_a:
    dct['dataframe'] = dct['dataframe'].dropna()
```

Documentation on [pandas.DataFrame.dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) is here.